# Comparing Column1 to Column 2 and writing to Column3 if match

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet linked to a SQL query in column [Raw Data]. After adding a few columns with formulas to clean up the raw data, i need to find if the value in column [ProcDataQ] exists in column [ProcDataO], all columns comprise to make Table1.

```
ProcDataQ | ProcDataO | Stat
--------- | --------- | ---- 
C1234     |   C7126   | Ordered
C8372     |   C6152   | No Order
C7126     |   C1234   | Ordered
```

I am able to do this with the below formula but i have more than 20,000 records and it takes on or around 30 seconds to load or refresh the table and i figured i could speed this up using a little vba that I'll trigger to run on the query refresh.

```
=IF(AND(LEFT([@[Raw Data]],1)="q", (NOT(ISERROR(MATCH([@ProcDataQ],[ProcDataO], 0))))),"Ordered", "No Order Placed")
```

fyi, i am running excel 2010 on PC.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: How do i loop through column ProcDataO to find any matches to ProcDataQ  and if a match is found, enter a value in column Stat? preferably using VBA since my excel formula take refreshes VERY slowly, even when sorting data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an IF and COUNTIF statement:

=IF(COUNTIF(range, item to look up)>0,"Ordered","Not ordered")